# Prove that this integral converges

Tags: integration

I'm trying to prove this integral 
$\int_0^{0.5}1/(r|lnr|^2)dr $
converges and I'm a bit stuck.

I know that $\int_0^{0.5}1/(r(lnr)^2)dr  = -1/ln(r)|_0^{0.5}$ which converges... but not quite sure if I can use this fact.

any hint would be really appreciated

Comment: Do you mean $\int\frac1r(\ln r)^2\,dr$ or $\int\frac1{r(\ln r)^2}\,dr$?

Comment: I ment $\int 1/(r*| ln r|^2)$

Comment: For real $x$, $x^2$ is the same as $|x|^2$

Comment: Of course you can use that fact.

Comment: I know its correct what you say but how come wolfram integrator doesnt give me a close form of this integral
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F(r*abs(ln(r))%5E2)

and for the case with no | | it does? :/

Comment: Try [this input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(r+*(ln(r))%5E2))

Answer (score 1):

We have $|\ln r|^2 = (\ln r)^2$ and thus

$$\int_0^{0.5}\frac {dr}{r\ln^2r} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\int_x^{0.5}\frac {dr}{r\ln^2r}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\left.-\frac 1{\ln r}\right|_x^{0.5}\right) =\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(-\frac 1{\ln 0.5}+\frac 1{\ln x}\right) = \frac 1{\ln 2}.$$